# How to Display Custom Token in Rules UI Data Selector?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

We use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and its submodule, Rules UI to manage our Rules. We have recently created some custom tokens, which are under the 'node' type. I have tested to make sure that these tokens 1) get the proper value and 2) are present among the Drupal tokens (by viewing them at /admin/help/tokens).

We would now like to use these tokens, both present under 'node'. However, they **refuse** to show up in the Rules UI. I have tried to add a condition to the Rule that 'Entity has field' of the custom token(s), but they do not appear there.

How can I make a custom token appear in Rules (UI), when it already exists in Drupal's token system?

**Update:**

The Token is an email address. It appears the token *will* appear in the field where I can select an email to be sent. However I would really like it to be available in the 'Entity has field' and/or the 'Data is empty' selectors, so I can choose whether or not to send the email based on whether the token has an email address associated with it.

Any ideas for getting it to appear in either of these locations ('Entity has field' or 'Data is empty')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 options you may want to try:

1. Rework your Rule so that part of the logic of it you move to another (new) Rules Component (which uses "node" as a parameter) and then in your rules component check in its conditions if those tokens become available.
2. Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module so that within your Rules Action you can add a "condition" where these tokens may show up.

As per your "*It appears the token will appear in the field where I can select an email to be sent*", either of both options should work, if you use those options AFTER the Rules Action where you can already use the token for sending an eMail.